# Overload Error in my Method

Tags: c#, class-library

I have created a Class library with a single method called createFile()
See below: 
[image: Class library]

I have another cs file - Program.cs where i want to call this method from my created library

[image: Program]

However I get an overload error when i try Run it

[image: Error message]

Comment: Did u try to build it ? Cuz it shouldn't give that error !

Comment: Hover over it, are you sure it's trying to use the method from your class library?

Comment: `ConsoleApplication1` and `BNCSharpLib` - are they in the **same** solution (sln) file or **different** solution files?

Comment: Same solution - Different Projects.

Comment: Does the console application have a **binary** reference to `BNCSharpLib`? Or a **project** reference. _Please check, don't guess._

Answer (score -2):

Try this steps:
1. Close studio
2. Clean “bin” and “obj” folders
3. Open project again